# How to get exception when killing process in java by Runtime.exec() command?

Tags: java, android

I have an app, where user can list all running tasks in system, and also can kill some if he wants.

My code here:

```
public void killProcess(String PID) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/kill " + PID);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Process has been killed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This works for me, but only when application can be killed by normal user, I have not granted the app a superuser permission and I don't want to, what I want is, to get a message `Permission denied` or `Operation not permitted` when normal user can't kill it. That's all. Any ideas ho to get this done properly?

I've seen also `Process.killProcess(int PID)` can be used as it is an android's method, but don't know how to get an exception here either.

Thanks

---

**EDITED**

working code:

```
public void killProcess(String PID) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/kill " + PID);
        p.waitFor();
        if (p.waitFor()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Process: " + PID + " has been killed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Argument must be process ID or kill process: " + PID + " is not permitted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this, just don't. It's anti-Android, not required and harms performance.  Task killers are only for people who do not understand the difference between a desktop OS and a mobile OS.

Comment: @Simon haha, I know from "googling" that this is bad...but it is an school project, and I'd like pass my subject, noone will use it...so should I tell teacher, sorry, I am not doing task manager, cuz it is forbidden? Maybe he will kick me out of his class, maybe he will understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `p.getErrorStream()` to read any error messages your kill `Process` prints to stderr. You can also check the return value of `p.waitFor()` to see if the command succeeded (0) or failed (otherwise).